# How can I launch different programs silently based on the OS version?

Tags: batch, autorun

I have two versions of my `autorun.exe`, one each for:

- Windows 7
- Older OSs

I need a way, (other than using .net or VB), to start silently with no window, check for the OS version, and start the appropriate exe accordingly.

I wrote a batch that works, but I can't start it silently from the `autorun.inf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) can perform this sort of operation and create a small executable which doesn't require .NET or any other runtime pre-installed.

```
Switch @OSVersion

    Case "WIN_7"
        Run( "versionA.exe" )

    Case "WIN_VISTA", "WIN_XP"
        Run( "versionB.exe" )

    Case Else
        Run( "versionC.exe" )

EndSwitch
```